# How do you apply an arbitrary numbers of arguments passed to function which is argument of another function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How would you apply a unlimited number of arguments to a function which is a parameter of another function?

This is what I tried:

```
var callIt = function(fn) {
    for(var i = 1; arguments.length + 1; i++){
        return fn(arguments[i]);
    }
 };
```

There is a function in the exercise which is used to convey what is being asked:

```
callIt(sumAll, 1);
```

Maybe I've had too many beers...

```
callIt(sumAll, 2,3) // 5 is expected but I got 2
```

Comment: Maybe ` return fn(arguments[i]);` solves your problem?

Comment: Thanks @StellaMaris, that gets this to pass `callIt(sumAll, 1)` but not `callIt(sumAll, 2,3)` or `callIt(sumAll, 4,5,6)` :)

Comment: If this is a homework exercise, there would be a hint in the first paragraph... if that paragraph is your own, you've hinted at the solution yourself ;) I suggest you `apply` it.

Comment: I thought `apply` is for arrays or does that include array-like objects as well?

Comment: That function would be useless, because you could do `sumAll(1, 2, 3, 4)` which is shorter and no wrapper is needed.

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz I'm not wondering because you return after the first step in your loop.

Comment: @zer00ne — as LihauTan has correctly shown, you can use `apply` with the argument object, but first (annoyingly) you have to convert it to an array. At least future developers will have it a bit easier with `Array.from()`. It is a shame `arguments` isn't just an array by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the [argument an array](https://davidwalsh.name/arguments-array), remove the first element, use `apply`.

```
var callIt = function(fn) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    return fn.apply(null, args.slice(1));
}
```

Or working from your code:

```
var callIt = function(fn) {
    var args = [];
    for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    return fn.apply(null, args);
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Lihau—that worked. I like the first though—pretty elegant!

Comment: As you are already using slice to convert the argument object to an array, `return fn.apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));` would be more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

```
function show()
        {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
            arguments[0](args);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> callIt(sumAll, 2,3) // 5 is expected but I got 2
> ```

`javascript` at Question `return`s from within `for` loop at first iteration. Also, `for` loop does not have a `condition` which would return `false`. You can utilize `rest parameter` to separate function parameter from remainder of parameters passed to `callIt`

```js
var callIt = function(fn, ...args) {
    var res = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        res += fn(args[i]);
    }
    return res
 };

var result = callIt(function(n) {
  return n
}, 2,3);

console.log(result);
```